# req.on('end') not running Firebase express Node.js Nylas

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create webhooks with Nylas, and in their [example](https://github.com/nylas/nylas-nodejs/blob/main/example/webhooks/index.js), there is a middleware (code below). I'm using a Firebase endpoint and my code is written in typescript. I've tried replicating the Nylas example locally in a new project by using ngrok and the middleware successfully returns a 200 status. However, when I use the exact same code in my Firebase functions, the middleware stops at `req.on('end` and **times out**, so I receive `console.log('2')` but not `console.log('3')`. Firebase claims that third party services are restricted until billing is set up. Could that affect the middleware? Why is `req.on('end` not firing?

```
  req.rawBody = "";
  console.log("1");
  req.on("data", (chunk) => (req.rawBody += chunk));
  req.on("error", (err) => res.status(500).send("Error parsing body"));
  console.log("2");
  req.on("end", () => {
    console.log("3");
    // because the stream has been consumed, other parsers like bodyParser.json
    // cannot stream the request data and will time out so we must explicitly parse the body
    try {
      console.log("4");
      req.body = JSON.parse(req.rawBody);
      console.log(req.body);
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send("Error parsing body");
    }
  });
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "5mb", extended: true }));
```

Comment: Are you actually making the request to Nylas or are you simply testing the middleware? If you are making the request billing is indeed required to be enabled.

Comment: Well, eventually I will make the request to Nylas, but currently times out in the middleware. Which shouldn't happen since it's only passing the `req.rawBody`. I'm assuming the middleware is only responsible for parsing the data, but I have no other speculation as to why it's timing out because the middleware works completely fine when I run it on ngrok locally. Only when I run it under firebase functions does it time out. I can see how the billing becomes an issue, but not so much for the middleware. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Got status 200 by using [this approach](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests) to parse the data.